# Почему такой результат умножения

Tags: c++

Почему так происходит ?
Код:

```
unsigned short x = 0 - 1;
unsigned short y = 0 - 1 ;
unsigned long z = x * y;
cout << hex << x << " \t" << y << " \t" << z <<  " \t" << x * y << endl;
```

Результат:

```
ffff    ffff    fffffffffffe0001        fffe0001
```

Comment: А что не так?

Comment: Мне интересно было почему последние два результата отличаются? fffffffffffe0001  и fffe0001.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@DUP](/users/4397/dup) "Мне интересно было почему последние два результата отличаются? fffffffffffe0001 и fffe0001."

Это для 64-разрядного CPU. long 64-bit, x * y неявно приводится компилятором к int (32-bit), при преобразовании в long знаковый бит размножается. Для 32-bit CPU последние 2 результата будут равны (fffe0001).

Вообще будьте осторожнее с вычислениями для операндов с **разной** разрядностью и unsigned. Лучше перед вычислениями явно делайте присваивания промежуточным переменным (меньше непоняток будет).

Answer (score 3):

Шутки приведения типов. Когда умножаете x*y, получаете 0xfffe0001, приведённое к типу int. Когда это выражение присваиваете его z типа unsigned long, оно приводится к типу long (расширением знака), получается fffffffffffe0001. Если выводите умноженный результат, то получаете fffe0001 в шестнадцатиричном формате (-131071 в десятичном). Вроде так